# Setting a button permanently enabled

Tags: android

I have a list of different buttons named stage1 to stage10. then the stage1 button is the only button that is enabled and the rest are disabled. after the user finished all the questions inside stage1, it will unlock stage2. How can I permanently set a button enabled so that every time the user exits the application and re open it, the button that is set enabled should still be enabled.

Answer (score 2):

You could store the information about which buttons were enabled in SharedPreferences. Once you come back you check which buttons were enabled last time and enable them programatically.

Answer (score 0):

Use some sort of storage, to save whether the user has already unlocked the stage.
It can be done with:

- SharedPreferences
- Database
- File

After it's done, you can check every button's 'flag', and set them accordingly when the page loads.

Comment: can you guys give me some samples codes on how to save a button in sharedpreferences? Im a newbie in android.

Comment: This link should explain everything pretty well:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref

But you're looking at it a little wrong. You don't need to save the button per say, what you want to do is, you want to add the button's name and its value (visible or not = 1 or 0) to the sharedpreferences and load them when the page is loaded.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your needs, there are different persistent storage solutions. You can check the options from [Android Storage Options](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref). Examples are included there.

Answer (score 0):

First you create a shared preferences class:

```
  public class AppPreferences {
      private static final String APP_SHARED_PREFS = "com.aydabtu.BroadcastSMS_preferences"; //  Name of the file -.xml
         private SharedPreferences appSharedPrefs;
         private Editor prefsEditor;

         public AppPreferences(Context context)
         {
             this.appSharedPrefs = context.getSharedPreferences(APP_SHARED_PREFS, Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
             this.prefsEditor = appSharedPrefs.edit();
         }

         public boolean getOnOrOff() {
             return appSharedPrefs.getBoolean("get_on_or_off", false);

         }

         public void setOnOrOFF(Boolean text) {
             prefsEditor.putBoolean("get_on_or_off", text);
             prefsEditor.commit();
         }
```

Then from your main activity:

```
appPrefs = new AppPreferences(getApplicationContext());

Button buttonOff = (Button)findViewById(R.id.B_off);
//to get preferences and set button
buttonOff.setEnabled(appPrefs.getOnOrOff());
//to set preferences
appPrefs.setOnOrOff(true);
```

Comment: should I set first the buttons' properties to disable in xml?

Comment: You can do as you like. Either will work. It is possible to change buttons' properties only in java.
buttonOff.setEnabled(true);//on
buttonOff.setEnabled(false);//off